# "Add Stack" not showing up in Concete5

Tags: concrete5

Just starting with Concrete5, and linking it.

But I wanted to create some code to be replicated in several pages.

So I've created a stack and added some blocks.

But when I return to the page and put on edit mode when I press a Area the "Add Stack" option doesn't show up.

I've this options:

```
- Add Block 
- Edit Area Design
- Add Layout
------------
- Edit Container Layout
- Edit Layout Design
- Save Layout as Preset
- Manage Presets
```

What am I missing?
I'm using the lastest version of Concrete 5.7.5.2

Answer (score 1):

A "stack" is just another block, so to add a stack open the "Add block" panel and choose "Stacks" from the dropdown.

[image]